# How to automate a task in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10

is there a gui application to automate a task, like the record function in automator on OS X?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to automate any task under any OS is [shell scripting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)

Alternatively, ask [Apple](https://www.apple.com/support/contact/) to release the source code to automator so we can compile it and include it in Ubuntu...